# How to check validate in android? and if both intime and outtime are empty then Toast or both of one empty then passed

Tags: android

if both **intime** and **outtime** are empty then Toast or both of one empty then passed

```
private boolean isValidate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(sp.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().length() == 0){


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Name !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }else{

    }

    if(etDate.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Date !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return false;
    }else{

    }
     //both intime and out time passed either one of passed here
    if(etintime.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter In Time !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }else{

    }
    if(etouttime.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Out Time !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }else{


    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  && conditional operator to perform logical And, in your case check both of your EditTexts if they are empty.

e.g.

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equals("") && editText2.getText().toString().equals("")){
//show Toast here.
}
```

Comment: if this helps, you can choose it as answer.